# Soapui property transfer JSON if statement

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I'm new to soapui and I'm trying to do a property transfer of the element in the list options which ha selected = true. The response is in JSON and I can select the element with the code `$.response.optionList[0].options[1].id` but rather then give the element number I would like to choose whichever has selected = true. Is this something you do with a groovy script? Does anyone have any suggestion?

```
{    
    "response": {

        "optionList": [
        {
            "options": [
            {
                "id": 10,
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "selected": true
            }
            ]  
        },
        {
            "options": [            
            {
                "id": 12,
                "selected": false
            }]
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are  you using property transfer test step after the rest request step?

You can use `Script Assertion` for the rest request step to achieve and remove property transfer test step.

Use below script:

```
//check if there is response
assert context.response, 'response is empty or null'
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)
def id
json.response.optionList.each{ optionItem ->
   optionItem.options.each { option ->
     if (option.selected == true) {
        id = option.id
     }
   }
}
log.info "id value when selected is true : ${id}"
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('ID', id?.toString())
```

If you need to access the above `id` from previous step response and use it later steps, use property expansion say `${#TestCase#ID}`

You can quickly try the above script online <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5098775123066880)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much for the help but actually in the respons, optionId have another element, please se updated response above. I tried to apply your code but get null pointer exception. I could not find a way to alter your scrip but tried to get only the first element of optionId.

Comment: What happened when try the above script. Believe that it should work. Give it a try.

Comment: The script worked before I added a second element to the optionList list. After I added element number two to optionList it gives that the id is null when selected=true

Comment: @Mikael, let me check. So, in your case, does the response always contains only one selected as true?

Comment: for the second element in optionList, selected can be true at the same time as only one of the options in the first element optionList can be true. it represents two radio buttons and a check box.

Comment: but I only want the id of one of the two options in the first element in optionList

Comment: @Mikael, just now updated the answer, please give try.

Comment: @Mikael, if the answer is helpful and resolves the issue, [appreciated if accepted as answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)